# Get values of two select with the same class

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

Here is my problem.
I have two select that I need to get values to submit them with ajax.
Depending on the situation one select is disabled the other one not .

When the first select is enable,  I can get the value from the select but when I disable the first one and enable the second one , the value return is null

How can I get the value of the second one ?

He is  a JS Fiddle to illustrate my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/mktknjsf/

```
$('#First').click(function () {
    $('#Bloc1').find('input, textarea, button, select,option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#Bloc2').find('input, textarea, button, select,option').prop('disabled', true);
});
$('#Second').click(function () {
    $('#Bloc2').find('input, textarea, button, select,option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#Bloc1').find('input, textarea, button, select,option').prop('disabled', true);

});

$('#Submit').click(function () {
    var i = $('.test').val();
    alert(i);
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `i` at `var i = $('.test').val();` is selecting both `select` elements with `class` `.test` at `click` of `#Submit` . Try selector

`$(".test:not(:disabled)").val();`

to filter `select.test` that does not have property `disabled` set to `true`

https://jsfiddle.net/mktknjsf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
var i = $('.test:enabled').val();
```

as in

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y13uyoym/)

But perhaps you meant to see both if neither were disabled?

```
$('#Submit').click(function () {
    var vals = [];
     $('.test:enabled').each(function() {
      vals.push(this.value)
     })
    alert(vals.join(","));
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pq5weds1/)